# Getting rsync to delete source files that already exist on destination

Tags: rsync

I have a cron job that uses `rsync` to periodically transfer all files that appear in a specific directory on server A to somewhere on server B. I use `--partial` and `--append-verify` as the files are large. I also use the `remove-source-files` option to deletes the files on server A when they are transferred. As per the man page, `rsync` only delete the source files after all file transfers have completed on a specific run.

This works fine most of the time, except if the transfer is interrupted partway through due to a network failure, after a few files have already been transferred. On the next run, the program sees some of the files already in the destination and correctly determines they don't need to be re-transferred. However, since they were not part of that transfer run, the files in the source server do not get deleted. Over time they build up.

Is there a way to tell `rsync` to delete the source files on the subsequent run, if they exist in the destination, or is this something I'll have to solve by writing my own scripts?

Comment: It may be helpful to list all the rsync options you are already using so other don't suggest ones that may already be in play.

Comment: Have you tried either the `--checksum` or `--size-only` options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, its not really much of an answer, because it's kind of a hack way of getting the results you are requesting.  So here goes:

If you trim out the `--append-verify` command and replace it with the `--update` command, leave all the other options and run the RSYNC without it.

This will delete all the source files while copying the files that have been modified.

Comment: `--update` may not work. Rsync could see the partial file on the receiver as newer than the source and skip it as not needing to be copied.

Comment: I tried it exhaustively, it worked on my sandbox for partials that had same stamps on the receiver.  I mean, I'm not really fond of my answer, it's truly lack-luster, but if you don't want to script something, it's a way to get by.  :-/

Comment: I will try this out the next time I get the problem, then come back to mark the answer. As luck would have it, the connection problems that have been so persistent have cleared up just when I wanted to try a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered an easy way:

```
rsync -rav --remove-source-files --backup-dir=<BAK> <SRC> <DST>
```

all files existing in DST and being detected as "changed" will be moved into BAK - now you can delete SRC folder and consider BAK as your new source folder.